# How can I install .NET 4.5.2 via PowerShell DSC?

Tags: powershell

I can install .NET Framework 4.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 using PowerShell DSC via the WindowsFeature resource and the NET-Framework-45-Core feature. My question is, how do I use PowerShell DSC to ensure that .NET 4.5.2 is installed?

Comment: Did you end up using DSC for this, or something else?

Comment: Chocolatey has an installer for 4.5.2, which is also PowerShell based. Have you investigated using DSC with Chocolatey? https://chocolatey.org/packages/DotNet4.5.2

Answer (score 14):

Not sure if this is still required by the OP, but I had the exact same challenge recently and found many problems with the installer itself, when trying to use just the package resource on a 2012 R2 Server. Ended-up having to write a script resource and use the web installer as the full package kept failing to decompress with a very generic error.

Anyway, here is a working script resource I ended up with:

```
Configuration Net452Install
{
    node "localhost"
    {

        LocalConfigurationManager
        {
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
        }

        Script Install_Net_4.5.2
        {
            SetScript = {
                $SourceURI = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/4/1/B4119C11-0423-477B-80EE-7A474314B347/NDP452-KB2901954-Web.exe"
                $FileName = $SourceURI.Split('/')[-1]
                $BinPath = Join-Path $env:SystemRoot -ChildPath "Temp\$FileName"

                if (!(Test-Path $BinPath))
                {
                    Invoke-Webrequest -Uri $SourceURI -OutFile $BinPath
                }

                write-verbose "Installing .Net 4.5.2 from $BinPath"
                write-verbose "Executing $binpath /q /norestart"
                Sleep 5
                Start-Process -FilePath $BinPath -ArgumentList "/q /norestart" -Wait -NoNewWindow            
                Sleep 5
                Write-Verbose "Setting DSCMachineStatus to reboot server after DSC run is completed"
                $global:DSCMachineStatus = 1
            }

            TestScript = {
                [int]$NetBuildVersion = 379893

                if (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' | %{$_ -match 'Release'})
                {
                    [int]$CurrentRelease = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full').Release
                    if ($CurrentRelease -lt $NetBuildVersion)
                    {
                        Write-Verbose "Current .Net build version is less than 4.5.2 ($CurrentRelease)"
                        return $false
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Write-Verbose "Current .Net build version is the same as or higher than 4.5.2 ($CurrentRelease)"
                        return $true
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Verbose ".Net build version not recognised"
                    return $false
                }
            }

            GetScript = {
                if (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' | %{$_ -match 'Release'})
                {
                    $NetBuildVersion =  (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full').Release
                    return $NetBuildVersion
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Verbose ".Net build version not recognised"
                    return ".Net 4.5.2 not found"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Net452Install -OutputPath $env:SystemDrive:\DSCconfig
Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager -ComputerName localhost -Path $env:SystemDrive\DSCconfig -Verbose
Start-DscConfiguration -ComputerName localhost -Path $env:SystemDrive:\DSCconfig -Verbose -Wait -Force
```

Comment: Great answer, this approach also works for .net 4.6.1.  I tried a variety of existing DSC integrations (chocolatey, cDotNetInstaller, etc...) and they all failed with the 4.6.1 installer.  This is the first one that worked. Kudos.

Comment: Agreed; nice answer. I want to mention this also works through Chef and the `dsc_script` resource.

Comment: I also confirmed this works with .net 4.7, with NetBuildVersion = 461310 and grabbing https://download.microsoft.com/download/A/E/A/AEAE0F3F-96E9-4711-AADA-5E35EF902306/NDP47-KB3186500-Web.exe

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Microsoft Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282127.aspx), the name of the feature to install should be one from the **Get-WindowsFeature** command's result. Thus, if .NET 4.5.2 does not appear in the list, you can't ensure it's installed via DSC.

> **Name** Indicates the name of the role or feature that you want to ensure
>   is added or removed. This is the same as the Name property from the
>   Get-WindowsFeature cmdlet, and not the display name of the role or
>   feature.

So I guess you'll have to install the major version via DCS (4.5), and then figure out the best solution to update it to 4.5.2.

Comment: Seems like a fairly major oversight. New PowerShell DSC can install software as new as two-and-a-half years old!

Comment: It's not an oversight. The .NET 4.5.2 runtime is *not* a Windows Feature, so it can't be installed using the WindowsFeature resource. It's available either through Windows Update  or as a separate download. The script will have to download and execute the appropriate installer.